# Assembling jasmin class leads to inverted operators and comparisons

Tags: jvm, bytecode, jasmin

When I try assembling my `test.j` jasmin file with the commandline `java -jar Jasmin.jar test.j` it generates the `test.class` file without any errors. All the code is the same except for the operators and comparisons, all my `+` will become `-`, the `==` all become `!=` and so on and so forth.

My `test.j` jasmin file adds 2 numbers and checks if these are equal to 7, if true print something, else print something else. At the end it will always print one line of text.

`test.j` file:

```
.class public test
.super java/lang/Object

.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
.limit stack 5
.limit locals 3

ldc 5
ldc 3
isub
ldc 7
if_icmpne L1
getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
ldc "It is not bigger"
invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(Ljava/lang/String;)V
goto LE1
L1:
getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
ldc "It is bigger"
invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(Ljava/lang/String;)V
LE1:
getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
ldc "this will always print"
invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(Ljava/lang/String;)V
return
.end method
```

Assembled `test.class`, the `5 - 3 != 7` should be `5 + 3 == 7` here:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] var0) {
        if (5 - 3 != 7) {
            System.out.println("It is not bigger");
        } else {
            System.out.println("It is bigger");
        }

        System.out.println("this will always print");
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad, It should say 5 + 3 == 7 in the .class file

Comment: `isub` is for minus; `iadd` is for plus. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jasmin code you posted contains `isub`, which is for subtraction, not addition. The assembler is correct. You are outputting assembly that does not match your intended behavior.